# Biblatex. APA style with annotated bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, bibliographystyle

I am trying to write a document which needs APA style referencing in text, but an annotated bibliography.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get both together?

I have tried `style=reading` option for biblatex (and I can change the options to get what I want in relation to the bibliography), but the in-text citations say "Author" rather than "Author (year)".

Comment: What exactly does "annotated bibliography" mean for you? (Since you can just populate the `annotation` field and `style=apa,` will print that without any issue, I assume you're thinking of something specific that this approach doesn't give you.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the response. It appears that the annotation will appear when I put it directly into the bibliography using APA style but not when I have it in a separate ```bibannotation-XXX.tex``` file! I might be able to manage with just including it in the .bib - even though the annotations might be relatively long. My issue was that I wrote the annotations using the separate files when using ```reading``` and was then trying to get the in-text citations to APA format.

Comment: If you set the `loadfiles` option `biblatex-apa` will also load your external annotation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` supports annotations in the `annotation` field and – if you enable the `loadfiles` option – also in external `bibannotation-<entrykey>.tex` files.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, loadfiles]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{bibannotation-elk.tex}
An annotation for this entry.
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, A. (1972). A theory on brontosauruses. Monthy & Co. An annotation for this entry.]

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try that. I actually had ```loadfiles=true``` when I was using ```reading``` but took that out when I was trying to get the APA working!